# Merging multiple values into one row in a new column Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Greetings Beautiful People!

I'm putting together a visualization for some customer *whoops edit* survey data. Unfortunately, the data modeling or end to end process throughout is non-existent

I have multiple columns as follows :

```
    What Role : Teacher, What Role: Engineer, What Role : Doctor
1   Yes,                 Yes,                 No, 
2   No,                  No,                  Yes,
3,  Yes,                 No,                  Yes,
```

so, what I *want* to do is create a new column and convert the Yes' into a new Value which matches the Header, so if doctor is Yes, then it would enter int a new Column:

```
    What Role?
1   Teacher, Engineer,
2   Doctor,
3   Teacher, Doctor
```

Could this be done by creating a dictionary then a for loop?

for example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("file.csv")

Dictionary_File = {'What Role?' : 'What Role : Teacher', 
'What Role?': 'What Role : Engineer', 'What Role?' : 'What Role : Doctor'}

for k,v in Dictionary_File.items():
   (df[k] = df[k] == 'Yes', 'Unsure here' + df[v])

df = df.drop(list(Dictonary_File.values()), axis=1)
```

So when it comes to the for loop I couldn't think or find a way to merge the values into something new (Other than manually changing all the columns Yes into a new value then merging..?)

any help would be much appreciated!

Cheers,

Comment: Unsure of the sudden downvotes - this was my literally my first or 2nd week into programming ! any advice to improve the question I'll be happy to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need first remove `What Role:` by `split`.

Then by boolean mask `df == 'Yes'` create joined values by [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

```
c = df.columns.str.split().str[-1]
s = np.where(df == 'Yes', ['{}, '.format(x) for x in c], '')
print (s)
[['Teacher, ' 'Engineer, ' '']
 ['' '' 'Doctor, ']
 ['Teacher, ' '' 'Doctor, ']]

df['new'] = pd.Series([''.join(x).strip(', ') for x in s], index=df.index)
print (df)
  What Role : Teacher What Role : Engineer What Role : Doctor  \
1                 Yes                  Yes                 No   
2                  No                   No                Yes   
3                 Yes                   No                Yes   

                 new  
1  Teacher, Engineer  
2             Doctor  
3    Teacher, Doctor
```

Comment: First solution is faster, so second is removed.

Comment: I remember when I first asked this and had no idea what the code meant, finally at a place where this feels totally natural and readable to me. Thanks so much Jez for helping the newbies in the community.

Answer (score 1):

Use

**Option 1**

```
In [1188]: cols = df.columns.str.split(': ').str[1]

In [1207]: df.eq('Yes').dot(cols + ', ').str[:-2]
Out[1207]:
0    Teacher, Engineer
1               Doctor
2      Teacher, Doctor
dtype: object
```

**Option 2**

```
In [1189]: df.eq('Yes').apply(lambda x: ', '.join(cols[x]), 1)
Out[1189]:
0    Teacher, Engineer
1               Doctor
2      Teacher, Doctor
dtype: object
```

---

Details

```
In [1190]: df
Out[1190]:
  What Role : Teacher What Role: Engineer What Role : Doctor
0                 Yes                 Yes                 No
1                  No                  No                Yes
2                 Yes                  No                Yes
```

Comment: Thanks buddy! I'll try this & the answer below! :)